# About a simple recursive function in python

Tags: python

I need to do a recursive function that works like this:

> input: 'word'
>
> output: ['word','ord', 'rd', 'd']

Now, the best way to do it its like this:

```
func(string):
    if not string:
        return []
    return [string] + func(string[1:])
```

But i'd like to do it in this way:

```
func(string, recursivelist):
    if len(string) == 0:
        return []
    recursivelist += [string]
    recursivelist += func(string[1:],recursivelist)
    return recursivelist
```

I know this is a bad way to do a recursive function, and i'm trying slowly to get the first approach, but just out of curiosity, why this code is not working?

The output is like this:

> ['word', 'ord', 'rd', 'd', 'word', 'ord', 'rd', 'd', 'word', 'ord', 'rd', 'd', 'word', 'ord', 'rd', 'd', 'word', 'ord', 'rd', 'd', 'word', 'ord', 'rd', 'd', 'word', 'ord', 'rd', 'd', 'word', 'ord', 'rd', 'd']

Comment: What do you mean "*is not working*"?

Comment: When you're adding the result of `func` to `recursivelist`, can you see how you're going to be adding a copy of `recursivelist` to `recursivelist`?   Change `recursivelist += func(string[1:],recursivelist)` to `func(string[1:],recursivelist)`

Comment: The output should be ['word','ord', 'rd', 'd']

Comment: Oh yeah, very simple, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each recursive call gets the *same* list, not a copy of it. So you don't need to add the return value of the recursive call, since they all modify the same list. It is enough to:

```
def func(string, recursivelist):
    recursivelist.append(string)
    func(string[1:], recursivelist)
    return recursivelist
```

Answer (score -2):

Simple solution not using recursion:

```
def func(word):
   for i in xrange(len(word)):
       yield word[i:]

>>> list(func("word"))
['word', 'ord', 'rd', 'd']
```

or if you don't want to use 'yield':

```
def func(word):
    return [ word[i:] for i in xrange(len(word)) ]
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all - please read what OP is asking

Comment: Just giving alternate code doesn't really answer the question. Also, I'm not sure yield counts as 'simple' for someone at OPs apparent level.

Comment: The original problem is not best solved with a recursive function so I was giving an alternative linear solution.